# Can I specify the publish target in an SDK style WiX project?

Tags: wix4

I'm attempting to create an installer using WiX4. I was able to successfully add a .wixproj to the solution using Heatwave, and I added ProjectReference tags for the relevant projects that I want to package. I want to be able to build from Visual Studio and also from the command line.

When I run the build, it appears to call dotnet build. For the dependent projects, I actually want the output of a publish, so currently I am working around this by creating a custom target that runs before the build and explicitly call publish using the Exec Command element.

However, I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this? I suspect that currently the build is happening twice, once for my custom build target and once during the build target.

Here's an example of what I have:

```xml
<Project Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk/4.0.0">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="MyProject.csproj" Platforms="Any CPU" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <HarvestDirectory Include="MyProject\bin\$(Configuration)\net7.0\publish">
      <ComponentGroupName>ComponentGroup</ComponentGroupName>
      <DirectoryRefId>INSTALLFOLDER</DirectoryRefId>
      <SuppressRootDirectory>true</SuppressRootDirectory>
    </HarvestDirectory>
    <BindPath Include="MyProject\bin\$(Configuration)\net7.0\publish" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="WixToolset.Heat" Version="4.0.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="WixToolset.Util.wixext" Version="4.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="CustomBeforeBuild" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="rd /s /q MyProject\bin\$(Configuration)\net7.0\publish" />
    <Exec Command="dotnet publish MyProject -c $(Configuration)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Is there a way to specify that I want to invoke `dotnet publish` on MyProject instead of `dotnet build`, using Msbuild, so that I can get rid of the CustomBeforeBuild target?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside your WixProj you add an item group to reference your project, in this reference, you add the Publish="true" attribute.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\YourProject\YourProject.csproj" Publish="true" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Let me share with you an example of how I use it

```xml
<Project Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk/4.0.2">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputName>App-Test</OutputName>
    <DefineConstants>
        ProductVersion=$(Version);
    </DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <HarvestDirectory Include=".\obj\$(Configuration)\publish\YourProject">
      <ComponentGroupName>HarvestedComponents</ComponentGroupName>
      <DirectoryRefId>INSTALLFOLDER</DirectoryRefId>
      <SuppressRootDirectory>true</SuppressRootDirectory>
    </HarvestDirectory>
    <BindPath Include=".\obj\$(Configuration)\publish\YourProject" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="WixToolset.Heat" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="WixToolset.UI.wixext" Version="4.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="..\YourProject\YourProject.csproj" Publish="true" />
 </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Thanks, this does actually work, with a few caveats. I still have to call my .wixproj with build instead of publish, and as you demonstrate in your bindpath, it is published to a path under the obj file rather than to the regular location. But other than that this seems to work as advertised.

Comment: If you're using publish profiles you may also need to add `<PublishProfile>ProfileName</PublishProfile>` to a `<PropertyGroup>` in the project  you want to publish. I don't know of any other way to specify what should actually be published.